# Need timer to run after 10 seconds in C#

Tags: c#

I am working with socket programing ,I can to check the live connection of Users after some time intervals such as 10 seconds.But currently, i have no idea. how i will do it.

Please help me. I shall be highly thankful.

Comment: Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: If you have to check at a regular interval, using Timer class would be better solution than having sleep thread

Answer (score 3):

From MSDN [Timer Class (System Timers)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

Below is an example from the MSDN page

```
[C#] 
public class Timer1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed+=new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        // Set the Interval to 10 seconds.
        aTimer.Interval=10000;
        aTimer.Enabled=true;

        Console.WriteLine("Press \'q\' to quit the sample.");
        while(Console.Read()!='q');
    }

    // Specify what you want to happen when the Elapsed event is raised.
    private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Include: `using System.Threading;`

I have no idea what you are doing (have code to show us?), but here's the general logic:

```
while (/*connection is active*/)
{
 //check connection
 Thread.Sleep(10000); //10 seconds
}
```

Comment: I would split long `Sleep` into loop of smaller ones with exit check.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your doing, and how you are checking for the connection.

You can use the Threading.sleep(); a timer, or depending on what your doing you might be able to use an event handler based off of connects / disconnects...